# I am coding in Android Studio, and I need to fetch and display a specific line of data from a specific webpage

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I am very new to coding in Java/Android Studio.  I have everything setup that I have been able to figure out thus far.  I have a button, and I need to put code inside of the button click event that will fetch information from a website, convert it to a string and display it.  I figured I would have to use the html source code in order to do this, so I have installed Jsoup html parser.  All of the help with Jsoup I have found only leads me up to getting the HTML into a "Document".  And I am not sure if that is the best way to accomplish what I need. Can anyone tell me what code to use to fetch the html code from the website, and then do a search through the html looking for a specific match, and convert that match to a string.  Or can anyone tell me if there is a better way to do this.  I only need to grab one piece of information and display it.

Here is the piece of html code that contains the value I want:

writeBidRow('Wheat',-60,false,false,false,0.5,'01/15/2015','02/26/2015','All',' ',' ',60,'even','c=2246&l=3519&d=G15',quotes['KEH15'], 0-0);

I need to grab and display whatever value represents the quotes['KEH15'],  in that html code.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Keith

Answer (score 4):

Grabbing raw HTML is an extremely tedious way to access information from the web, bad practice, and difficult to maintain in the case that wherever you are fetching the info from changes their HTML.

I don't know your specific situation and what the data is that you are fetching, but if there is another way for you to fetch that data via an API, **use that instead.**

Since you say you are pretty new to Android and Java, let me explain something I wish had been explained to me very early on (although I am mostly self taught).

The way *people* access information across the Internet is traditionally through HTML and JavaScript (which is interpreted by your browser like Chrome or Firefox to look pretty), which are transferred over the internet using the protocol called [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). This is a great way for humans to communicate with computers that are far away, and the average person probably doesn't realize that there is more to the internet than this--your browser and the websites you can go to.

Although there are multiple methods, for the purpose of what I think you're looking for, *applications* communicate over the internet a slightly different way:

When an android application asks a server for some information, rather than returning HTML and JavaScript which is intended for human consumption, the server will (traditionally) return what's called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (or sometimes XML, which is very similar). JSON is a very simple way to get information about an object, and put it into a form that is readable easily by both humans (developers) and computers, and can be transmitted over the internet easily. For example, let's say you ask a server for some kind of "Video" object for an app that plays video, it may give you something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Gangnam Style",
  "metadata": {
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0",
    "views": 2000000000,
    "ageRestricted": false,
    "likes": 43434
    "dislikes":124
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "username": "John",
      "comment": "10/10 would watch again"
    },
    {
      "username": "Jane",
      "number": "12/10 with rice"
    }
  ]
}
```

That is very readable by us humans, but also by computers! We know the name is "Gangnam Style", the link of the video, etc.

A super helpful way to interact with JSON in Java and Android is Google's [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which lets you cast a Java object as JSON or parse a JSON object to a Java object.

To get this information in the first place, you have to make a network call to an **API**, Application Programming Interface. Just a fancy term for communication between a server and a client. One very cool, free, and easy to understand API that I will use for this example is the [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com/), which just spits back information about movies from IMDB. So how do you talk to the API? Well luckily they've got some nice documentation, which says that to get information on a movie we need to use some parameters in the url, like perhaps

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Interstellar
```

They want a title with the parameter "t". We could put a year, or return type, but this should be good to understand the basics. If you go to that URL in your browser, it spits back lots of information about Interstellar in JSON form. That stuff we were talking about! So how would you get this information from your Android application?

Well, you *could* use Android's built in HttpUrlConnection classes and research for a few hours on why your calls aren't working. But doesn't essentially every app now use networking? Why reinvent the wheel when virtually every valuable app out there has probably done this work before? Perhaps we can find some code online to do this work for us.

Or even better, a library! In particular, an open source library developed by Square, [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). There are multiple libraries like it (go ahead and research that out, it's best to find the best fit for your project), but the idea is they do all the hard work for you like low level network programming. Following their guides, you can reduce a lot of code work into just a few lines. So for our OMDB API example, we can set up our network calls like this:

```
//OMDB API
public ApiClient{
    //an instance of this client object
    private static OmdbApiInterface sOmdbApiInterface;
    //if the omdbApiInterface object has been instantiated, return it, but if not, build it then return it.
    public static OmdbApiInterface getOmdbApiClient() {
        if (sOmdbApiInterface == null) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint("http://www.omdbapi.com")
                    .build();
            sOmdbApiInterface = restAdapter.create(OmdbApiInterface.class);
        }
        return sOmdbApiInterface;
    }
    public interface OmdbApiInterface {
        @GET("/")
        void getInfo(@Query("t") String title, Callback<JsonObject> callback);

    }
}
```

After you have researched and understand what's going on up there using their documentation, we can now use this class that we have set up anywhere in your application to call the API:

```
//you could get a user input string and pass it in as movieName
ApiClient.getOmdbApiClient().getInfo(movieName, new Callback<List<MovieInfo>>() {
//the nice thing here is that RetroFit deals with the JSON for you, so you can just get information right here from the JSON object
            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject movies, Response response) {
                Log.i("TAG","Movie name is " + movies.getString("Title");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("TAG", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Now you've made an API call to get info from across the web! Congratulations! Now do what you want with the data. In this case we used Omdb but you can use anything that has this method of communication. For your purposes, I don't know exactly what data you are trying to get, but if it's possible, try to find a public API or something where you can get it using a method similar to this.

Let me know if you've got any questions.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, but as the poster below assumed, I only have the webpage.  But I appreciate the help, and I am sure I will be coming back to look at this code for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

As @caleb-allen said, if an API is available to you, it's better to use that.

However, I'm assuming that the web page is all you have to work with.

There are many libraries that can be used on Android to get the content of a URL.
Choices range from using the bare-bones HTTPUrlConnection to slightly higher-level HTTPClient to using robust libraries like Retrofit. I personally recommend Retrofit. Whatever you do, make sure that your HTTP access is asynchronous, and not done on the UI thread. Retrofit will handle this for you by default.

For parsing the results, I've had good results in the past using the open-source HTMLCleaner library - see http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net

Similar to JSoup, it takes a possibly-badly-formed HTML document and creates a valid XML document from it.

Once you have a valid XML document, you can use HTMLCleaner's implementation of the XML DOM to parse the document to find what you need.

Here, for example, is a method that I use to parse the names of 'projects' from a <table> element on a web page where projects are links within the table:

```
   private List<Project> parseProjects(String html) throws Exception {
        List<Project> parsedProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();

        HtmlCleaner pageParser = new HtmlCleaner();
        TagNode node = pageParser.clean(html);
        String xpath = "//table[@class='listtable']".toString();
        Object[] tables = node.evaluateXPath(xpath);

        TagNode tableNode;
        if(tables.length > 1) {
            tableNode = (TagNode) tables[0];
        } else {
            throw new Exception("projects table not found in html");
        }

        TagNode[] projectLinks = tableNode.getElementsByName("a", true);
        for(int i = 0; i < projectLinks.length; i++) {
            TagNode link = projectLinks[i];
            String projectName = link.getText().toString();
            String href = link.getAttributeByName("href");
            String projectIdString = href.split("=")[1];
            int projectId = Integer.parseInt(projectIdString);
            Project project = new Project(projectId, projectName);
            parsedProjects.add(project);
        }

        return parsedProjects;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I only have the webpage available.  I think all I would need is the barebones approach to getting the content of the URL.  All I want to do is go to this webpage: http://www.antoncoop.com/markets/cash.php       and get the cash price for wheat.  Is it possible to use HtmlCleaner to get the contents of the URL, or would I need multiple libraries in order to get the contents of the URL and parse for the cash price of wheat?  Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: HtmlCleaner does not provide HTTP access - you'll have to do that yourself with one of the java/Android-provided classes (like HTTPUrlConnection http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.htmlor HTTPClient http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) or use a third-party library like Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to edit the webpage to add hyper link to specified line of that page you can use this way

First add code for head of line that you want to go there  in your page

### head your text if wanna

Then in your apk app on control click code enter
This.mwebview.loadurl("https:#######.com.html#target")

in left side of # enter your address of webpage and  then #target in this example that your id is target.
Excuse me if my english lang. isn't good